# Same version of Chrome, two different behavior regarding sha1 deprecation

Tags: certificate, google-chrome

i'm well aware of the changes made to Chrome 42 and sha1 signed certificates.

Here a short reminder : https://blog.filippo.io/the-unofficial-chrome-sha1-faq/

Our client reported this problem and I've explained what was causing it. Here the screenshot he gave me :

[image: Client report]

The problem is that I've upgraded chrome on an offline VM (using the same version as the client : 42.0.2311.90 m) with the standalone setup and I can't see this behavior (tried the same website as well as other internal sites with sha1 expiring after 2017 certificates). All locks are green :

[image: What i see on the VM]

Do you have an hint of what could cause this difference of behavior between 2 same version chromes ?

Thanks

Edit : here the certificate details that should trigger "unsecure https" in chrome 42 :
[image: certificate details]

Edit2 : I did a comparison between the VM chrome://conflicts page and the client ones. When i saw a diff in the crypto API related to this kb : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3033929 (read tech note inside) I thouth maybe Chrome was relying on the OS API to check the validity of the certificate (MS, google and Mozilla agreed on this 2017 end of support date). 
I've applied the KB but so far no changes. Still green lock. I'm going to open a bug to chromium support list. I'll update this post later.

Comment: What does Qualys test say? Are the sites behind a CDN?

Comment: This is an internal website so i can't test it with ssl lab. As for the platform it's just two IIS7 servers with Microsoft NLB.

I'll update my post with the certificate details.

Comment: This is probably because the two systems use different crypto libraries (one is a Windows system, the VM is a Linux I presume) and that somehow triggers a potential bug where Chrome doesn't realize the site uses deprecated crypto.

Comment: I wasn't aware of such possible bugs. The client use windows 7, the VM is MS Win2008R2 64-bit.
There're no automatic updates on the VM could it be related to missing security KB on it that chrome would rely on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the flags controlling how Chrome behave regarding `sha1` certificates are remotely controlled (Google servers). In Chrome 42 (and maybe 43) it was implemented fail-open thus giving green lock on off-network VM.

In Chrome 44 it's implemented fail-closed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The behavior described here (https://blog.filippo.io/the-unofficial-chrome-sha1-faq/) is controlled with flags.

Comment: (missclicked, here the complete answer)

The behavior described here (https://blog.filippo.io/the-unofficial-chrome-sha1-faq/) is controlled with flags. Those flags are by default remotely controlled (chrome connect to google server and retrieves them). That's why with Chrome v42 you don't have the same behavior between a computer which has internet connection and one which don't.